# Javascript for loop behaving as though 2=21

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've found a lot of discussion about javascript validation functions for forms but can't find anyone running into this particular problem.

In the code below, even though there are 21 values in the array 'fields[]', the for loop ends after 2 iterations. The last alert it pops reads "1 < 21" - it's as though it thinks 2 is not less than 21.

I thought it might be a data type error but can't figure it out. Thanks to anyone who can see it.

```
var fields = new Array;
var fields = [
    document.forms["survey"]["Q1Age"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Q2Gender"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Q3Education"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Q4Field"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Q6Other"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Q7Edited"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["UserAccount"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Whole"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Sections"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Images"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Keywords"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["writing"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["trustworthy"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["accuracy"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["bias"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["info"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Viz1"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["Viz2"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["VizDescription"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["VizOver"].value,
    document.forms["survey"]["submit2"].value
];

var err = 0;

//Start Validation Loop
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    alert(i + " < " + fields.length); //test how many iterations

    //Check Fields in Array to Make Sure they are not Empty
    if(fields[i].value == "" || fields[i].value == "Select One") {
        err++;
    }
}

if(err === 0) {
    //Submit Form
    //document.survey.submit();
    return true;
} else {
    //If there are errors, return false and alert the user
    alert("Please fill out all of the fields.");
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Your code seems ok to me. Are there no error messages in your console?
Most likely something breaks on the line in which you check fields[i].value (is value even an existing property?)

Comment: check value is not null. I think document.forms["survey"]["Q3Education"].value returns null. alert(); all the array values then see.

Comment: Let me be clearer. I actually get two alerts, one for each of the first two iterations of the loop where i=0 and i=1. Then it ends for some reason.

Comment: Does your console show any exceptions? They are likely to break loops…

Comment: @Aniket: The `.value` property of an existing input should always be a string, not null.

Comment: I did print fields[] in an earlier test and they all exist, some as text, some as numbers, some empty. In fact, Q3Education is the first one that has a text value. Maybe something strange is happening with that...

Comment: Also keep this value in a variable and then compare with that variable once try : var values = fields[i].value; and then  if((values  == "") || (values  == "Select One")){alert("hiii");}

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the input's `value` when you are creating the array your array elements are already strings, so in your if statement you are trying to get property `value` from a string, which is probably causing the script to end cause it is trying to access an undefined property

Your if statement should be this.

```
 if(fields[i] == "" || fields[i] == "Select One") {
        err++;
 }
```

Comment: He's already getting the value when declaring the array, so his if statement further does is basically doing something like `document.forms["survey"]["Q1Age"].value.value`

Comment: correct. got it. he trying to access `.value` on array element and which is string. Thanks.

Comment: awesome, thanks, .value was grabbing the value out of the form field and I mistakenly used it again.

Comment: (and yes... *she* was trying to access value on a string. ;)

Comment: @andiii: But that should not have made your loop stop at the second iteration. Did it?

Comment: @bergi, yeah, it's weird - i guess it worked for two iterations because that happened to be the first value that wasn't empty when i was testing.